# Como Importa dados em Excel para tabela de atributos no ArcGis?

Tags: maps

Pessoal estou tentando importas uma tabela de Excel (xlsx) para a tabela de atributos do ArcMaps.
Queria entender qual o caminho para fazer esse processo.
Imagino que seja pelo o Xtools mais não sei como realizar o processo inicial.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?